# get data from an API

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to extract data from the Api link with Curl. The problem is that my link have no fields posted. I have tried this but I got an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: xml in C:\wamp\www\OOP PHP\GetHtml.php on line 17
```

The code is as given below:

```
$handle=curl_init();
$url="https://www.domain.com/api/list/0/";
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($handle);
//$xml=simplexml_load_string($result);
//$json=json_encode($xml);
//$array=json_decode($json,TRUE);

curl_close($handle);

print_r($xml);
```

I also tried with 'file_get_html' still not working, if there is a good solution please help me.

p.s: After 4 hours of searching everyone was using 'file_get_html' and it's working perfectly but not always, and also i've found a solution using 'HttpSocket' in Cakephp, and as i'm just a novice in Cakephp i can't work with it.

Sorry i'm so damn sleepy !!!

Comment: Sorry i was sleepy and messed it up, i've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `file_get_contents()` way..

```
<?php
$data=file_get_contents('http://mangaeden.com/api/list/0');
$data1=json_decode($data,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data1);
```

### The cURL way..

```
<?php
$handle=curl_init();
$url="http://mangaeden.com/api/list/0";
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($handle);
$data=json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($handle);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: sorry i was sleepy, the semicolon is not the issue, i've tried many things else i got 'undefined $variableName' error in the curl_exec() line or an empty page

Comment: Ok can you post your full code on the question ?

Comment: it's my full code only a short script. I'm working with cURL.

Comment: https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/

Comment: So you want them in an array right through a cURL response?

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati, Code updated.

Comment: oh dude nice i was missing CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. thanks bro, and if you have a mail or something to contact you thx